# C# - Reading a textfile realtime

Tags: c#

working on reading a textfile in realtime in my program, but i cant get it to work.
Here is my code, no errors:

```
  public void Main2(string[] args)
    {
        string[] fileContents;

        try
        {
            fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\log.txt");

            foreach (string line in fileContents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

No text gets printed out in the console window.

Comment: I don't understand. What is not working exactly?

Comment: Do you mean you can't read a file opened by another process? The question makes no sense otherwise

Comment: maybe you can try displaying the exception message instead of throwing it away

Comment: No no, its reading from a textfile, and i want to display the results in the console window. (Console.WriteLine) but its not reading the textfile, and the textfile is not beeing used by another program either.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? What is the error message then? What do you mean by real-time? Why are you trying to catch a `FileNotFoundException`? If the file doesn't exist, how do you expect to read from it?

Comment: Is it not reading it or not displaying it? Have you checked that the path to the file is correct (for example by using File.exists)?

Comment: By the way, `public void Main2(string[] args)` is not a main method (not sure if that is related to your problem, though...)

Comment: Actually @elgonzo is right... why is your main-method called main2?

Comment: Enable a break point in the code and step thru the code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons you won't see any output:

1. The file is empty;
2. The console window is closed before you see anything appearing on it.

The second one is the only code related problem I see in your code. You don't wait until the user gives an okay for closing the console.

Put this in the end of the `Main` method:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

You need to press `enter` to close the screen then.

Comment: @user263029: Need more help?

Answer (score 1):

There could be 2 reasons I think of:

1. Your file is empty.
2. You don't call the method `Main2()`.

Enable break points and step through the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine just see below code is updated only one thing I am added `Console.ReadLine();` at the end of the main function and also changed your function name as Main2 to Main. You want to press enter key to console close the screen then.

**Updated Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] fileContents;

        try
        {
            fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\log.txt");

            foreach (string line in fileContents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        //Here is my extra one line code            
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**Note:**

Confirm your text file is exist with some text content.